# How to use a custom HttpClient with Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

i'm working on porting over an existing Angular application to use SSR. I've found that, when doing one of my server calls, it was not waiting for the server call to finish before sending down the HTML. What i've found is that, since i am using a custom HTTP client, it is not waiting for the data to return before sending the html. If I swap out my injected HTTP Client with the built-in Angular one, it properly waits for the call to render in the html and then returns to the UI. Any ideas on how to get this working properly with a custom HttpClient? I am using custom httpClients that extend the built-in one so that I can have multiple different interceptors based on different use cases.

Custom Http Client

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpServiceOpen extends HttpClient {
  constructor(backend: HttpBackend, private injector: Injector) {
    super(new CustomHandlerService(backend, injector, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS_2));
  }
}
```

Org Service

```
constructor(
    private httpOpen: HttpServiceExternal,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private snackbar: MatSnackBar
  ) {}

  organizationUrl = `${environment.api}/organization`;

  get() {
    // return this.httpClient.get(`${this.organizationUrl}`); will work
    return this.httpExternal.get(`${this.organizationUrl}`);
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does that help? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15278

Comment: I got really excited when I saw that issue yesterday, but unfortunately it looks like a lot of that discussion applies to the old Http module before the new HttpClient came out. I couldn't even find some of the classes they are referencing as solutions in `angular/universal` or `angular/angular` repos.

Comment: Oh right, I did not pay attention. aybe it's the same principle/issue with `HttpClient` though, but I did not go dig in the code...

Comment: Yeah I had never navigated the universal code before so it's a bit hard to see where it is handling waiting for async call. My plan right now is to put a really bad bandaid in place, finish the SSR conversion, then find a proper solution if no one else happens to know on here.